# App store Missing Purpose String in Info.plist error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store

I use RN 0.59.10, I have just received this error, when I have uploaded previous versions last week - I didn't get this error. I don't use location details in my app.

Any ideas why this is happening?

> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to give proper message for asking location permission. why you need location or why its required.

Here its example. you can enter this message in your `info.plist` and change as per your requirements.

Example Message - **App would like to use your current location to display it on the app, also for directions and estimation of your travel times. It is secure and private.**

For last one message regarding your `UIWebView`, it's says that **`UIWebView` is deprecated and you have to stop using and used `WKWebView`**. If you have not used in your application then check in third-party libraries or .pod files. Somewhere its used so apple has given message.